# Fix access violation at glDrawArrays()?

Tags: c++, opengl

This is my code:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include "App/Includes/glew.h"
#include "App/Includes/glfw3.h"

struct ShaderPipeline
{
    unsigned int program;
    unsigned int vao;
};

void createShaderPipeline(ShaderPipeline& pipeline, const char* vertexContent, const char* fragmentContent)
{
    pipeline.program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int id;

    // Create vertex shader
    {
        id = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(id, 1, &vertexContent, NULL);
        glCompileShader(id);
        glAttachShader(pipeline.program, id);
    }

    // Create fragment shader
    {
        id = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(id, 1, &fragmentContent, NULL);
        glCompileShader(id);
        glAttachShader(pipeline.program, id);
    }

    glLinkProgram(pipeline.program);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &pipeline.vao);
    glBindVertexArray(pipeline.vao);
}

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow* window;

    // Create window
    {
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, true);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, false);
        window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Pixel Madness", nullptr, nullptr);
        // Fullscren: window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Pixel Madness", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), nullptr);
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    }

    glewExperimental = true;
    glewInit();

    std::map<std::string, ShaderPipeline> shaderPipelines;

    // Load shader pipelines
    {
        createShaderPipeline
        (
            shaderPipelines["p"],

            R"glsl(
                #version 150 core
                in vec2 pos;

                void main()
                {
                    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 0.0, 1.0);
                }
            )glsl",

            R"glsl(
                #version 150 core
                out vec4 color;

                void main()
                {
                    color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                }
            )glsl"
        );

        // Setup input
        {
            unsigned int id = glGetAttribLocation(shaderPipelines["p"].program, "pos");
            glVertexAttribPointer(id, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(id);
        }
    }

    // Create vertex buffer
    {
        unsigned int vbo;
        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    }

    // Test
    {
        std::vector<float> vertices
        ({
            0.0f, 0.5f,
            0.5f, -0.5f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f
        });

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(float), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW); ///
        glUseProgram(shaderPipelines["p"].program);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    }

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE))
        {
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
        }
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I have switched to OpenGL recently from DirectX and I don't have any idea what can be the problem. The code is supposed to draw a white triangle. I'm following some online tutorials how I did with DirectX... It is tested on VS 2017 debug x64.

Tutorial page: https://open.gl

I checked if shaders compile succesfully, and `glGetError` returns 0 before drawing function.

Comment: Your array buffer must be bound before you can call `glVertexAttribPointer`. The reason for this is that the OpenGL VAO remembers which buffer is bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` and uses that when rendering.

Comment: Thx very much! This was the problem.